# Pass value from input to controller without $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have problem with following code. I can solve the issue with $scope, but this time request to do it without using $scope in controller. I am using "controller as" to control the view.

```
<body ng-app="appModule" >
<div ng-controller="calculatorController as calc">

<input type="number" name="firstDigit" placeholder="insert num" ng-model="calc.firstDigit">

<input type="number" name="secondDigit" placeholder="insert num" ng-model="calc.secondDigit">

<span>{{calc.result}}</span>

</div>
</body>

(function(){
    angular
        .module("calculatorModule")
        .controller("calculatorController", calculatorController)
            function calculatorController(){
                var calc = this;
                calc.result = calc.firstDigit + calc.secondDigit;
        }
})();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you have two options - you can do it with watchers, or with a function to get the result. I prefer the latter, but it's up to you. Here's an example of how you can get it to work:

Side note - learn the `controller as` syntax, it will save you thousands of headaches down the road with nested scoping and child-parent relationship issues with `$scope` -- [here's a great article explaining controller as](https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/)

```js
(function () {
  angular.module("calculatorModule", [])
    .controller("calculatorController", [function() {
        var calc = this;
        calc.getResult = function() {
          return calc.firstDigit + calc.secondDigit;
        }
        calc.result = calc.getResult();
    }]);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="calculatorModule" ng-controller="calculatorController as calc">

  <input type="number" name="firstDigit" placeholder="insert num" ng-model="calc.firstDigit">

  <input type="number" name="secondDigit" placeholder="insert num" ng-model="calc.secondDigit">

  <span>{{calc.getResult()}}</span>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but one more question. If I place your code to self-invoking function. then code not working. I am trying to avoid global variables and placing code in self-invoking function.

Comment: @Srdjan No global variables are created with this code.. But just for good measure, I put an IIFE around my code and it works exactly as before. Are you changing something?

Answer (score -1):

Your module definition is false!

Should be

```
module("calculatorModule", [])
```

Comment: Not exactly - it is not a module definition, it is a module getter to define the controller on a module that already exists. You just assumed that the module was not defined before.

Comment: This should be a comment, as it does not answer the question. Also, you should point out that the `ng-app="appModule"` on the body tag does not match the module name defined in the JS.